Is circuit current determined by battery reaction speed?
I'm reading a book called "Practical Electronics for Inventors" by Paul Scherz and Simon Monk and I have encountered a picture of a battery (figure 2.5. in the book) that says:
$$``Zn(s) + 2OH^-(aq) \to Zn(OH)_2(s) + 2e^-$$
$$2MnO_2(s) + H_2O + 2e^- \to Mn_2 O_3 + 2OH^-(aq)."$$
The book says that this reaction happens in a battery from the picture at the rate of 10^17 reactions per second for 0.100 A.
However, each reaction spawn 2 electrons with elementary charge \$1.6 \times 10^{-19} C \$ each. This in 1 second we can only get $$3.2 \times 10^{-19} \times 10^{17} = 0.03 A.$$
Where does the rest 0.97A come from? Or is it an error in the book?

The rest is just 0.07 A, not 0.97 A.

This book contains a lot (and I mean it, a lot) of errors, and there are several online errata you can find. I did not spot this figure (which comes on page 10, by the way!) in the errata lists. I am assuming it is an error. Your calculations seem correct.
